# $ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-Cr^2} (1+r^2)^{-p/2} r^{d-1} dr=?$

Tags: integration

Fix $C>0, p>0, d\in \mathbb N.$

Can we compute
$$ I:=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-Cr^2} (1+r^2)^{-p/2} r^{d-1} dr?$$

**Edit**: Can we expect that  $I\leq C_1(C)$ where $C_1$ the constant is depending $C?$  If so, what is $C_1(C)$?

Comment: One relation I got is $$I(p,d)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac d2)}{\Gamma(\frac p2)} C^{(p-d)/2} I(d,p)$$

Comment: @Szeto: I've edited the question. Can we expect some upper bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $p>0$ we have that

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-Cr^2}(1+r^2)^{-\frac{p}{2}}r^{d-1}\: dr < \int_0^\infty r^{d-2}e^{-Cr^2}r\:dr$$

then let $x = Cr^2$

$$\int_0^\infty r^{d-2}e^{-Cr^2}r\:dr = \frac{1}{2C^{\frac{d}{2}}}\int_0^{\infty} x^{\frac{d}{2}-1} e^{-x}\:dx \equiv \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}{2C^{\frac{d}{2}}}$$

which is a constant upper bound for the integral.